# Removing (hidden) information from MS Word header templates

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document file upon which I need to build the final version document. I happened to look at exif data of this doc, & noticed certain words & sentences that are no where in the document body. For example, 'Draft document only', 'Refer to Person X', etc.

To investigate further, I made a copy of this doc & changed the file ext to .zip, then unzipped it & looked into the resulting xml files. I find that `header*.xml` files have the above sentences / words. I am trying to figure out a way to remove these words/lines from the document.

I've tried finding the words/lines in header / style configuration but it isn't there. `Track Changes` is off, and `File|Info -> Properties` do not reveal the said words/sentences either. Using MS Word for Macintosh, version 15.

I've looked into all sections, headers & footers.. The only location I find these hidden words / sentences, is in `header2` & `header3` `.xml` files.

Today, I did another test - I copied entire content from source document (problem document A) to a new document (test document B). I saved Doc B, and then deleted everything. So, Doc B is now blank (no content). Then I looked into this doc B, and the same hidden words / sentences are still present in the header1.xml file... It looks like the problem is with the default template, specifically with the H1, H2, H3 definitions, since they are custom ones used by technical writing team

Nothing is returned in (advanced) search, and I also looked for section breaks in the blank document. There is no section break. This new document is basically a blank doc, with no headers/footers/body content/formatting etc...

Can someone pls suggest a quick way to clean this up? Thnx.

**Edits**: updating the post with what I've tried.

Comment: Have you checked each section in the document? How are they setup (different odd/even, different first)? If not try setting them that way, which will allow the checking of each by insert temp page breaks. There are 3 headers and 3 footers per section.

Comment: @RichMichaels Yes, I've looked into all sections, headers & footers.. The only location I find these hidden words / sentences, is in header2 & header3 .xml files..

Comment: @RichMichaels I've added my reply. Also updated the original post with what I have tried till now..

Answer (score 0):

Some recommendations:

1. Turn on Hidden Characters toggle. Home tab Pilcrow button.
2. Use Advanced Find and Replace to search all headers, footers, and body of document.
3. Maggie the file, which is copying everything from one file, except the last empty paragraph mark, and pasting it into a new document. After doing this you will have to recreate the last section's header and footer.
4. Delete each section break in the document, which will clear out all headers and footers. Clear last remaining header/footer. Check document and if clear of issue, reinsert section breaks.
5. Open the source template as a document and check if these hidden items can be found in it.
6. Your version of Mac Office is severely out-of-date. 16.15 is the current regular release. Your Microsoft AutoUpdater will also need to be updated. Downloads for the updates, including MAU, can be obtained from this Microsoft site [Update History for Office for the Mac](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-for-mac).

Comment: So, after opening the normal.dotm, it showed a blank doc only. Did a search for words, but nothing. No sections etc. Another test I tried is, I moved this default Normal.dotm from default location - Closed Word, and Re-open the documents A & B. Both still have the same hidden words / sentences. I am totally out of ideas on this now.

Comment: I thought you said there was a custom template. Another idea, why not just edit the XML?

Comment: Yes, looking at style options, there are several additions to header (h1, h2, h3) formatting, & TOC. I most certainly did not put any template `.dotm` since I ran the installer (from the corporate file share). I did try to remove hidden words & sentences from xml files yesterday. After updating the files, I zip'd them up, & renamed to `.docx`. It wouldn't open however, throwing an error saying the file is corrupt. As a last resort, I am considering uninstalling ms office & installing once again...

Comment: Why would you do that, uninstall office? Upgrade the version you have.